# How can I update one view of list in addwidget?

Tags: android, widget

In my widget, I wrote a RemoteViewsService to display some pictures. When the image was downloaded, I want to update one view to show this image,what can I do?

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(final int position) {
     final RemoteViews mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.item_widget);
     Glide.with(context).load(HomeWidget.list.get(position).remote).downloadOnly(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
           @Override
           public void onResourceReady(File resource, GlideAnimation<? super File> glideAnimation) {
               HomeWidget.list.get(position).local = Uri.fromFile(resource);
               sendBroadcast(new Intent(HomeWidget.IMAGE_LOAD));// this will update all views but not one view.
               //how can I update only this view after ?
}
```